# How do I find out what privileges I've earned before 200 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

You can look at the reputation graph; but only after 200 reputation, which I don't have.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) which has a complete list of all [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

[image: all privileges]

A green check-mark in front of the privilege indicates if you earned it.

If you click on the links to read the [details about the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) you can see at the right hand side of the screen as well if you earned it already:

[image]